# I can locate the XPATH

Tags: python, selenium

I can locate the XPATH of the element that I want, however it will not allow me to click
.......................................................................................

```
<a href="/traderoom" target="_self" class="Button Button_orange Button_big Button_bold css-u4v0q0 e1y8wypm7"><span>ทำการซื้อขายได้ </span></a>
```

...............................................................................

```
enter driver.find_element_by_xpath('a[1][@href='/traderoom']').click() here
```

Comment: Please provide the link to the website that you are trying to scrape. Also, did you try other methods like `find_element_by_css_selector`?

Answer (score 1):

xpath - `.//a[contains(@class,'Button_orange')]`

Answer (score 0):

Should grab the first tag and click it.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[@href='/traderoom']")[1].click()
```